# How do i regulate fake avatars in my VR-MMORPG?

Tags: law, computers, virtual-reality

I am the developer of Feudal souls, a fantasy open world VR-game with 2 million of players. My game is very big. Players constructed small towns in the first year and killed only 1 boss.

Now is the second year and the first big factions emerged. Everything was fine, but there is a problem. A teenager tried to kill himself by the fault of a man using a female avatar. The kid was married in game and was scammed.

However, this is not the first problem of its type, but it was the most serious. **How do I regulate the fake avatars if my VR-Platform is fully immersive?**

How would laws affect my game?

Comment: … add something like teamspeak/skype into game? Like in h1z1 i think…

Comment: @JanIvan By full immersion i mean that your mind is transferred to the game,You can have any voice you want.Thats the problem!

Comment: If your mind is transferred you could just make it a rule to automatically make men male characters and women female characters. Or you need some other form of authentication before being allowed to play the game, like having a real-life authority check if your avatar should be allowed. It's your world, you decide.

Comment: @Secespitus Im a gamer not a master of c++ so i need some help here.

Comment: … maybe facebook connection and ppl will decide by themselfs if they see fake profile there or not…

Comment: @AlexDarkshine If you are a developer for the game in your story you should be able to code, but that's not the point. I mean that if your company had a way for a fully immersive game that transfers the mind of your players you could just check the mind of the players to automatically determine their sex and only allow them to play that sex if you are set on making this a rule of your game.

Comment: The scenario you provided does not fit the description of the problem. There were two real players, one of whom used a male avatar and one of whom used a female avatar. Nothing about this was fake, aside from the fact they're avatars in a video game, of course. You may want to specify what constitutes a fake avatar as opposed to a real one.

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with worldbuilding and should rather be asked at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here. In "normal" games, it's accepted that avatar is not a person, merely represents a person. If, per comments, game actually transfers mind, the avatar becomes a person. Given ultimate flexibility of representation, in best post-human practice players would obviously remodel virtual bodies as they see fit, perhaps identifying more with digital "body" than real one. No more anchored by genetics, they are free to be taller (or opposite if they wish), more athletic etc. than their born bodies are. Switching sex is no more fake than any other change.

Comment: It's a fantasy game. You have avatars running around as elves, faeries, and animated piles of rocks. The fact that avatars don't represent the player is already embedded into the core fabric of the experience. Anyone who's not emotionally mature enough to understand that shouldn't be playing games with strangers on the internet to begin with.

Comment: Like in Sword Art Online: use a [Hand Mirror](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Hand_Mirror) to force them appear like they are in real life... Then let the female hunt begin ;)

Comment: This may be a better fit for the Community Building Stack Exchange

Answer (score 9):

When you start a game there is name of the game. It fade out to black. Then on a black screen big bold white letters appears and a voice of Macho Man reads them. They say:

**THIS IS A GAME. YOU CAN BE ANYONE IN IT, SO CAN OTHER PLAYERS. TRUST NO ONE, DON'T TREAT IT MORE THAN A GAME.**

Then softer voice says: There are no women on the internet.

Comment: Interesting idea. But IMO hard to tie in into supposedly fantasy setting. When reading this warning, I was imagining voice distorting each few words into different voice. Some male, some female, some electronically distorted and even one with ultimate villain grade booming echo.

Comment: Nice. Especially the "other player can be anyone" in villainous voice. Mark Hamill Joker for example.

Comment: And make it say "There are no men on the internet." if the user is a women.

Comment: @PyRulez You must be new to the whole internet thing http://i.imgur.com/f2rLQ.png

Comment: "You are probably the only human left."

Answer (score 3):

One thing that must be understood about an MMORPG is that it is not just a game, it is also a form of social networking. Unlike Facebook, where you are (theoretically) forced to represent your actual self, in avatar-based social networks like an MMO, the very appeal of the medium is that people are free to create an avatar that is NOT them. They have anonymity and psychological freedom to act in ways that they would be much more inhibited against if they were not anonymous. This has good sides and bad sides (like ganking or camping other players, etc). THE biggest factor in the success of the genre is that very anonymous networking capability.

Eric Reis tells a very interesting story about IMVU, a pioneer avatar-based social networking app in his book "The Lean Startup". Early user testing found that while people thought the app was cool and would happily create avatars, they did NOT want to then invite their real world friends the way a conventional social networking site worked (which was the original idea the developers had had for market expansion). Instead, testers found it much more interesting to try to make NEW friends on the site, safe behind the anonymity provided by the avatars. This was a BIG psychological insight and the key to the success of MMORPGs. On traditional social media, people are very conservative about forming new networks. 90% of what people do on things like Facebook is look up old classmates or friends who moved away or family members. On avatar-based social networks, things are the opposite. People generally do not bring in their real life social networks as readily as they form NEW social networks, which oftentimes transcend the original game they were formed in.

Harnessing that social networking power is the key to the success of titles like World of Warcraft (in my opinion), the most successful title in the MMORPG genre.

If you decide that you want to force players to behave the way they would in a traditional social network, you are going to work against the fundamental psychological dynamic that leads to a successful MMO in the first place. You will break your community (because people will NOT want to cooperate), and by doing so, you will undercut the game to the point of failure.

There are plenty of systems that can be employed to attempt to police account creation behavior (linking account identities to credit cards and limiting the number and types of characters that can be created comes to mind as pretty easy). It is possible to do what you want, but it is highly unwise. An MMO without a healthy community is nothing.

Comment: However, what if there is external pressure to enact some kind of disclosures, as was implied by the question?  How would you respond, if you were the CEO and designer, to accusations that the VR pushed an sublegal teen to a psychological break–down and suicide?  Et c.

Comment: Honest to God, if that happened, I would hype the shit out of it. I would get all over the internet with ads talking about how "you can't handle this game!!!" "This game is SO real!!!" I'd put up tons of splashy warnings and spin articles about how "This game is so real it's dangerous!!!" -I'd get about a million hits just out of curiosity. No such thing as bad publicity. It is NOT the game designer's fault that some people are unstable, sorry. It's the same BS as the endlessly repeated lie that violence is related to video game violence. No connection has ever been found.

Comment: Hmm, you know, this answer is actually probably the most worldbuilding of all the others — part of the problem is that the question deals with the metaworld outside the VR, whereas it doesn't address the VR worldbuilding well enough.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago there was a rumour about a MMORPG wanting to do what you say (World of Warcraft? I don't remember). The most insightful comment in slashdot about this subject was: "so, no roleplaying allowed in this massive multiplayer roleplay game?"

**TL; DR;**

You have a roleplaying game. You don't want people to play roles, only playing as themselves. I don't think it's going to be a success, but it all depends on playability. And good graphics, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to regulate the avatars?
Sounds like that's the wrong solution to your problem.

Putting a notice up about it being a game and not to take it too seriously is probably the best you are gonna do in this instance.

Especially seeing as there are many trans/intersex people who would have issue with being branded as M/F (perhaps wrongly.)

Include a notice about catfishing, maybe ask players not to form relationships.

That's the best you're going to be able to do. The same sort of thing could happen with any player being misleading about anything, not just gender.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh quite the interesting question, here are a few ideas:

### Connect with social media

On registration, make the players connect with a social media account that confirms their gender or contains photo's of the user. I believe software like that on the Nintendo Wii can create a Mii avatar based on the photo you choose. Maybe you can implement some kind of software that scans a picture, and builds a avatar looking like the person on the photo. If you only want to know their gender just get that info from their account information.

### National Identification Number

I don't know if this is possible, but maybe somehow you can get to link the governments database to your game, where people have to create accounts with a attached Social Security Number or something like that. This way you can confirm the person is not fake and you can get gender information and possible scan the photo printed on the ID card.

Comment: "make the players connect with a social media account that confirms their gender" what are their options? because I can bet you someone will complain. The OP must just make it that the helmet used for the full dive scans the users face. When the marriage ceremony takes place the bride and groom' scanned images appear.